# Lack of anything shown on Android Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I have the following layouts XML called `list_item_layout.xml`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/String_height"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/String_height"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/String_height"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/String_height"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drexel.jacky.weather" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

In the GUI the design is like this:

[image]

This is the Java code that gets the data from Weather Underground (this is in a `doInBackground` thread for networking):

```
        String key= "someKey";

        String sURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/someKey/geolookup/q/autoip.json";

        // Connect to the URL
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();


        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); // may be Json Array if it's an array, or other type if a primitive



        // Get some data elements and print them)
        String city = rootobj.get("location").getAsJsonObject().get("city").getAsString();
        String sURL1 = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + key + "/hourly/q/PA/"+city+ ".json";
        URL url1 = new URL(sURL1);
        HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        request1.connect();
        JsonParser jp1 = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root1 = jp1.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request1.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj1 = root1.getAsJsonObject(); // may be Json Array if it's an array, or other type if a primitive

        String hour;
        String date;
        String humidity;
        String image_url;
        int l = rootobj1.get("hourly_forecast").getAsJsonArray().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            hour = rootobj1.get("hourly_forecast").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("FCTTIME").getAsJsonObject().get("hour").getAsString();
            date = rootobj1.get("hourly_forecast").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("FCTTIME").getAsJsonObject().get("weekday_name").getAsString();
            humidity = rootobj1.get("hourly_forecast").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("temp").getAsJsonObject().get("english").getAsString();
            image_url = rootobj1.get("hourly_forecast").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("icon_url").getAsString();
            Weather weather = new Weather(city,hour,date,humidity,image_url);
            data.add(i, weather);

            Log.d("Hour: ", hour);
            Log.d("Date: ", date);

            //Insert data into the database
            Sql_Open_Helper sql_open_helper = new Sql_Open_Helper(this.context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = sql_open_helper.getWritableDatabase();
            if(this.c) {
                sql_open_helper.remake(db);
                this.c = false;
            }

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("Temp", humidity);
            values.put("Hour", hour);
            values.put("Date", date);
            values.put("City", city);

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert("Weather_Table", null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
```

I have been trying to get strings to show up on my Note 3 (it's a 1080x1920 resolution) using the following lay out, but with absolutely no progress made.

When I compile the app and load it using Android Studio, the activity is simply blank.

I tried a bunch of things. I made sure that the JSON parsing library is indeed returning the data such as hour, image URL, temperature, etc, and it does work (I created that library as a command line application first).

However, the data is just not showing up. The weird thing is, I do not even see any errors at all when I compile.

Could someone with much more Android experience than me help me debug this?

EDIT:

The following is my `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Create weather list for handling database
    Sql_Open_Helper sql_open_helper = new Sql_Open_Helper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sql_open_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    int hour = sql_open_helper.getHour(db); //Geting the last hour


    //Geting current hour for checking with in the last hour
    int current_hour = 14;
    //DateFormat Hhour = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:00 a");
    //int current_hour = Integer.parseInt(Hhour.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).split(":",2)[0]);


    //Compare the last hour with the current hour
    if(current_hour <= hour) {
        ArrayList<Weather> weather_list= sql_open_helper.addWeatherToList(db);
        MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, weather_list,false);
        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        l.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    }


    else {
        Bg_task bg_task = new Bg_task(this);
        MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, bg_task.getData(),true);
        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        l.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
        bg_task.execute();
    }
}
```

This is the class `MyArrayAdapter` which I wrote for the adapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Weather> array_weather;
    private boolean b;
    private boolean c;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Weather> objects,boolean b) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_item_layout, objects);
        this.context = context;
        array_weather = objects;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout,null);
        }

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView1.setText(array_weather.get(position).getCity());
        textView2.setText(array_weather.get(position).getHuminity());
        textView3.setText(array_weather.get(position).getHour());
        textView4.setText(array_weather.get(position).getDate());
        if(b){
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);//Display Image
            new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(array_weather.get(position).getImage_url());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: okay, so where do you call for instance TextView.setText("my weather");? is it in a listview? then you need an adapter, if not, you need to inflate your layout and set your objects to the preffered items.

Comment: I just tried to add a random button/text to the GUI. It did not show up when I loaded the app to my phone. I have a feeling it's because I didn't set something necessary in order to show that activity on the app.. I have also added the adapter class. To answer your question, it is in a list view, and I do have an adapter.

Comment: okay, your activity layout is has the listview widget in it right? and also are you certain that your if condition about the hour checks out to be true? check that, because if gets it in oncreate and if its empty it goes to retrieve it from the net  but does not update it, is that right? also to your second comment you tried to add button to the activity xml right? and it didnt show up? maybe your listview is match_parent check that too

Comment: Thanks, I will get back to you @Elltz

Comment: @Elltz Interesting. So if I comment out the if-statement in the `Bg_task.java`, and purely use the `Else` statement's code, I am able to print out the data that's parsed from `Weather.java`. Then, if I comment out the else-statement, and uncomment the if-statement, the data shows up!

Comment: wait is that a question sir? my suggestion was your if condition tends out to be false when you start your app, and since you had no mechanism that checks if your database had be filled up to populate your arraylist it fetchs it alright but no population so your list stays empty so yea let your else be the if and your if be the else and have encupsulate the population of your list in a method and call that method in onpostexecute of your async task so you can your list updated when you see new entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some changes after completion of async task.
in onPostExecute add below code :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {             
      MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, getData(),true);
      ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
      l.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);   
}
```

And your Activity look like below :

```
//Compare the last hour with the current hour
if(current_hour <= hour) {
    ArrayList<Weather> weather_list= sql_open_helper.addWeatherToList(db);
    MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, weather_list,false);
    ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    l.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
}


else {
    Bg_task bg_task = new Bg_task(this);
    bg_task.execute();
}
```